# Função Toogle Select

Tags: javascript, array, angular, typescript, for

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

Tenho uma lista de endereços que vem dinamicacmente do banco, de acordo com o que é cadastrado pelo usuário.

Preciso habilitar somente um endereço, sendo assim, quando é ativado um botão é desativado todos os outros.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
changeAddress(data) {
    if (data.status_info_end === 0) {
      data.status_info_end = 1;
    } else {
      data.status_info_end = 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrap-end" *ngFor="let data of totalend">
    <div class="wrap-inner-end-one">
      <div class="inner-header-end"> {{data.bairro_user}} - {{data.cidade_user}} - {{data.estado_user}}</div>
      <div class="central">{{data.cep_user}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap-inner-end-two">
      <span class="bt-change" [ngClass]="{'bt-changed' : data.status_info_end}" (click)="changeAddress(data)">
        <span class="round-bt" [ngClass]="{'rounded-bt' : data.status_info_end}"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Faça uma função para setar o campo "status_info_end" para 0 de todos os elementos do array. Você consegue fazer isso com um foreach...
Execute ela toda a vez que você clicar e somente após a execução dela você ativa o elemento que você deseja....